# Extract function from plot

Tags: plotting

Consider that we have some plot in Mathematica notebook, like an ordinary `plot = Plot[f[x],{x,xmin,xmax},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->...]`. Next, assume that `f[x]` has been forgotten by Mathematica (like, a part of the code has been deleted, or "Quit kernel" has been applied). Is it possible to extract `f[x]` from `plot`, i.e. is there some operation that allows obtaining `f[x]` by applying some operation with `plot`?

Comment: If you go `plot//InputForm` (or `FullForm` - and you can do it to the image stored in a notebook as well) you’ll get a giant output, but you’ll be able to see the actual code held by Mathematica. Generally, it’s full of line objects of `GraphicsComplex` which all have numerical data. If you had a hint on what the original function was, you might be able to fit it to the data stored there, but I don’t think you can recover the function perfectly.

Comment: @MassDefect, This way will not give you a function. The graphics of `Plot` stored in notebook is a postscript-like object, i.e. there are a lot of coordinates of points and curves but there is not an original function behind them

Comment: You can recover the GraphicsComplex (or point data) from the graphics and then fit the data to a function using one of several of the built-in functions.  The fitting  process may yield the original function.  For example, generate 100 points of sin(x), then use FindFormula and include Sine in the list of target functions.  I suspect this will return sin(x).

Comment: @Rom38 Right, that’s exactly what I meant. Sorry if I wasn’t clear. All that’s stored in there is raw data as lines and graphics complex objects.

Answer (score 1):

For Example:

```
plot = Plot[{x^2 - 1/4 x^3, x Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
points = Cases[plot, Line[linedata_] -> linedata, Infinity];
FindFormula[#, x, 1] & /@ points
```

Out=`{1. x^2. - 0.25 x^3., x Sin[x]}`